# How do I multi boot XP with a Unix like OS

Tags: linux, unix, multi-boot, beos

I want to code some simple personal projects on the Unix-like partition while doing everything else on my XP partition.

Can someone recommend the solution that takes up the smallest footprint in size and processing power that still delivers value? I want to learn how to code in a Unix environment.

I'm trying Cygwin but my first impression is its a bit clumsy. Would a dual boot with BeOS be better? And how would I do it?

Thanks.

EDIT: I need to be able to run both OS'es at the same time. This is very important for me. However, my laptop is pretty crappy and that's why I ask for something that has a low CPU/RAM footprint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options to get the feel of a "real" distribution

1. Install Unix/Linux on a separate partition. Most distributions nowadays are smart enough to create the necessary entries in the partition table for you to dual boot.
2. Use the new OS as a Virtual Machine image. You can use [Sun Virtuabox](http://www.virtualbox.org) for this. This way the whole guest OS will be sitting inside a virtual machine and you are free from the headache of dual booting , partitions etc. The speed may be a issue but thats OK i guess as a tradeoff.

Comment: I have tried VirtualBox and it's very slow on my computer. I'd like to be able to have a completely separate OS that can run at the same time as XP and at a good speed. Does anything like that exist?

Comment: "completely separate OS that can run at the same time as XP" - This is what Virtual machines are supposed to do :)

If speed is an issue i suggest you go with my 1st option i.e. reinstall the OS on a new partition.

Comment: Would I be able to run both OS's at the same time?

Comment: Well, no, not without a virtual machine. You'd have to shutdown one and boot into the other if you wanted to switch.

Comment: So Windows XP doesn't have anything like the Mac bootcamp? How about Win7?

Comment: Deleted my answer in lou of the edited question. Your best bet is #2 from LatishS answer.

Comment: @Jack bootcamp is not what the op wants. Bootcamp requires you to dualboot. They want simultaneous os's. A vm basically.

Comment: MrStatic I am the OP! But I was almost positive that Bootcamp lets you run both OS'es at the same time..

Comment: You may want to have a look at the following Wikipedia entry to get a better idea 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_%28software%29

Answer (score 2):

Depending what you are doing how about using a something like [this](http://www.geekshells.org/)? There are a few people who let you have access to their own machine try Googling something like "free shell access".

Once you have an account log in with [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

Comment: I think THIS is the best deal! +1 for an anti-headache solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Wubi](http://wubi-installer.org/), [Windows Services for Unix 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=896C9688-601B-44F1-81A4-02878FF11778&displaylang=en), or re-try VirtualBox with a lighter-weight Linux distro, such as [Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org/).

If none of these (or the other mentioned) options work for you, you'll likely need to upgrade your laptop. If you do, make sure that you get a processor that supports [hardware virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Hardware_support).